# Backbone JS Datatable Integration

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, datatables

I'm building an application that is based primarily on Backbone JS and have been really impressed so far. There is a portion of the app, however, that demands a fairly flexible table/grid layout that would allow some client-side filtering/searching/column-based filtering etc...

I've used Datatables in the past and it seems like it would be a great fit, but I am having some issues integrating the Backbone Models/Collections into the Datatable init.

One of the members on the DT forums suggests taking advantage of the mDataProp attribute ([DataTable Forums](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/6302/dt-with-backbone.js/p1)), but I have been unsuccessful so far.

I was hoping somebody might be able to point me in the right direction so that I can use Datatables to view my collections and items, and still have access to all the great event-binding etc that Backbone offers.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a thread that provides insight on how others are solving a similar problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/backbonejs/SjawlO5ENzc

Comment: DataTables and Backbone are great libraries but they overlap with functionality - they aren't perfect match. It seems that [recline.js](http://reclinejs.com) may be a better solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about dataTable but it looks like you can use the `toJSON` function on the Backbone Collection for your `aaData` value.

Here's an example

```
$('table').dataTable({
  "aaData": yourCollection.toJSON(),

  "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "Engine",   "mDataProp": "engine" },
    { "sTitle": "Browser",  "mDataProp": "browser" },
    { "sTitle": "Platform", "mDataProp": "platform" },
    { "sTitle": "Version",  "mDataProp": "version" },
    { "sTitle": "Grade",    "mDataProp": "grade" }
  ]
});
```

Comment: That looks like it could be the right way to go! In regards to rendering the individual item views themselves, I guess that would be related to the mDataProp? Currently, I'm rendering them by looping through the collection, rendering a JST template, injecting the model attributes and appending the new row to the existing table tbody.